# How to return one controller method from another?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a method that response to ajax call and return a view to ajax with a big query, and of course this method have `(Request $request)`.

So in the another method I want to return view of above method with it's data, how to return above method when it give some request data?

please note that **when the `request->query` is empty, the method return all data with `query=''`** and it is correct.

```
public function item_search(Request $request){
    if($request->ajax()){
        $result = MyModel::where('id' , $request->query)->get();
        return view('admin.ajax.searchResult')->with(['result' => $result ]);
    }
}

public function second_method(){
    // there is not any $request
    // how to set $request->query = '';
    return $this->item_search($request);
}
```

my second_method() not give any request, it run by another route,

now the `second_method()` called. how to call `item_search()` method from that ?

Comment: Just a recommendation, you may want to rephrase your question. From your second function your other doesn't have reference to request. Therefore if it is null and searching for an id of null that isn't gonna work.

Comment: Maybe describe that you have a controller entry method and then a method on that controller because as of now you can't tell which method is being invoked through your routing.

Comment: still not clear to me !!!!!

Comment: Just add `Request $request` to your second method and you will have it, or use `request()`

Comment: Ya lk77 is right, I just didn't want to assume... It feels gross though without all the requirements or information